# How to protect against email enumeration on sign-up

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth, brute-force, google-cloud-identity

Google suggest to [Enable email enumeration](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) , but despite that being enabled, when a user (with intention to discover if the given email address exists on the app) tries to sign up ( register) with a email and if the email exists, the Google Identity-platform reveals that the emails does exists.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the partial out of the fact that the Email protection is enabled

```
    {
      "name": "projects/601070666666/config",
      "signIn": {
        "email": {
          "enabled": true,
          "passwordRequired": true
        },"emailPrivacyConfig": {
    "enableImprovedEmailPrivacy": true
  }
```

I followed all the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection)

Comment: I was having the same issue for awhile and then realized it was my fault because I didn't apply it to the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

Email enumeration protection only makes sense for apps where self-serve-signups are disabled (ie. Every user must be created by an admin).

If this wasn't the case, what should happen when a user tries to create an account with an already registered e-mail? Since the account cannot be created, en error must occur. If you try to obscure the error but it happens every time with that e-mail and not others, then what's happening would be obvious for an attacker.